# Routes in bottle which proxy to another server

Tags: python, http, web-applications, proxy, bottle

I have a bottle.py application which has a number of routes already built. I would like to create a new `get` route which, when accessed, passes the request along to another HTTP server and relays the result back.

What is the simplest way to get that done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle, all you need is to install the wsgiproxy module and do this:

```
import bottle
from wsgiproxy.app import WSGIProxyApp

root = bottle.Bottle()
proxy_app = WSGIProxyApp("http://localhost/")
root.mount(proxy_app,"/proxytest")
```

Running this app will then proxy all requests under /proxytest to the server running on localhost:80. In practice, I found this didn't work without taking extra steps to remove hop-by-hop headers. I took the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1283467) and stripped it down to make a [simple app that successfully proxies the request](https://gist.github.com/2888380).

Comment: wsgiproxy seems unmaintained: last release in 2010, homepage link is dead-ish (redirects to archive.org, badly).